# ng-model not selecting values from dropdown list which are generated by ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I am using `ng-repeat` to generate multiple drop down. But after storing the values it is not selecting the dropdown values as previously selected. In this example it should automatically display teacher1, teacher3 and teacher5 as selected values.

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="(i,teacherList) in Trip.teachers track by $index">
        {{Trip.teachers[$index].id}}
        <select m-required="true" ng-model="Trip.teachers[$index].id" class="teacher form-control" >
            <option value="">Select Teacher</option>
            <option ng-repeat="teacher in teachers" value="{{teacher.id}}">{{teacher.name}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <button ng-click="addTeacher();">Add Teacher</button>                      
    <button ng-click="removeTeacher();" style="display:none;" class="removeTeacher">Remove</button>
</div>
```

and my angular code as below:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {  
    $scope.Trip={
        teachers : [
            {"name":"teacher1","id":"1"},
            {"name":"teacher3","id":"3"},
            {"name":"teacher5","id":"5"}
        ]
    };
    $scope.teachers=[
        {id:"1","name":"teacher1"},
        {id:"2","name":"teacher2"},
        {id:"3","name":"teacher3"},
        {id:"4","name":"teacher4"},
        {id:"5","name":"teacher5"},
        {id:"6","name":"teacher6"}
    ];
    $scope.addTeacher=function(){
        $scope.Trip.teachers.push({"name":"","id":""});
        document.getElementsByClassName("removeTeacher")[0].style.display="block";      
    }
    $scope.removeTeacher=function(){
        $scope.Trip.teachers.pop();     
        if($scope.Trip.teachers.length==1){
            document.getElementsByClassName("removeTeacher")[0].style.display="none";
        }
    }
})
```

Here is the link to JSFiddle:
[http://jsfiddle.net/dipgupta1986/10z7mda2/10/](http://jsfiddle.net/dipgupta1986/10z7mda2/5/)

Comment: can u clarify.. `it should automatically display teacher1, teacher3 and teacher5 as selected values`.. where it should display?

Comment: all the drop down selected value by default

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to show the default value pre-selected, you can use `ng-options` and `ng-model` for setting the default value, by rewriting `select` as below :

```
<select m-required="true" ng-model="Trip.teachers[$index]" 
ng-options="option.name for option in teachers track by option.id" >
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cryostat/10z7mda2/13/)

[ng-Options Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But what is the problem if i change "option.id" to "option._id" and all the "id" in $scope.teachers as "_id" .  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/dipgupta1986/92ucuujw/)

Comment: @Ankita Mishra ... Could you please check what is the problem?

Comment: @DipeshGupta It seems that you missed to make the same change in `Trip.teachers` array, as it still has `id`, instead it should be `_id` now. [Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/92ucuujw/1/)

Comment: Problem is in my real time scenario in "$scope.Trip.teachers" the "id" is "id" and  in "$scope.teachers" "id" is "_id"..  See my demo above. That's why i didn't change the id in "$scope.Trip.teachers". How can i achieve that?  @Ankit Mishra